# Bootcamp: Black screen shows after Windows 10 installation

Tags: bootcamp, high-sierra, windows

I have a MacBook Air with OS X High Sierra. I tried to install Windows 10 by selecting the top and the bottom selections in Bootcamp, which installs the setup on a USB and partitions a section for Windows 10. Bootcamp successfully installs it and boots into Windows 10 setup.

After I complete the setup, it boots into Windows 10. That’s where the error is. It restarts and goes to a blank screen. The screen is not off, and the computer isn’t off either. I booted back into Mac OS and tried to boot back into Windows 10, and the black screen reappears.

Here is a video of what happens, [Bootcamp: Black screen shows after Windows 10 installation](https://vimeo.com/273048505).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently my Bootcamp Assistant's Windows support folder was wrong, and the graphics drivers broke when it tried to install them. I just used VMWare to simulate windows 10 and wintousb to install windows on an external drive, and ran it on my laptop. I also moved another copy of windows support folder onto the drive, and only ran the internet drivers, and now Windows 10 works on my MacBook Air.

Comment: Just a note. If you use this method and try to play games, it will give you an error: "DX11 feature level 10.0 is required to run the engine". To solve this, you will need to update the graphics drivers, and will cause the screen to turn black.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else coming here, try this simple solution first.

Disconnect the power (MagSafe plug). If the display comes on, it means your power profile is set to turn brightness down when the AC is plugged in.

**Solution:** While power is unplugged, login and verify that the brightness controls work. Then plug power in and turn the brightness up. For some drivers, those brightness control don't work, and I've seen drivers that install with brightness set to zero by default.

Answer (score 1):

A mac uses the camera to detect light and adjust brightness and Windows can become confused.

If your Mac previously worked fine, just keep the old software and old drivers. Normal hardware work well with old software and updating is always painful and expences of failure. I installed 5.1 Boot Camp because my MacBook Pro is 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Since the windows logo appears, it seems to me that there is an error in the installation of Windows.

If I were you, I would try to reinstall Windows and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: I deleted and reinstalled it, but still the same problem.